# Events in Ext.ux.IFrame

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

How use events in Ext.ux.IFrame class: beforeload && load?
Source code http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-2/source/IFrame.html#Ext-ux-IFrame

```
Ext.create("Ext.ux.IFrame", {
    id: "id",
    src: "http://google.com"
    listeners: ...
});
```

or

```
{
    xtype: "uxiframe",
    id: "id",
    src: "http://google.com",
    listeners: ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your question is not very clear, not sure how you got an upvote, but I think this is what you want:

```
Ext.create("Ext.ux.IFrame", {
    id: "id",
    src: "http://google.com",
    listeners: {
        load: function(iframeComponent)
        {
            //code here
        },
        beforeload: function(iframeComponent, src)
        {
            //code here
        }
    }  
});
```